# Android: How to check if a button from a randomised array is correctly pressed

Tags: android, button, random

I need to design an activity on android that has 6 buttons and all but one of these buttons starts off with the same icon. The one that doesn't is randomly selected and after a certain amount of time, the odd one out is masked to look the same as the rest. The user then has to identify the odd one out and if they are correct it replays the activity. If they are wrong then it needs to finish.

I have managed to create the activity so that it does all of the above apart from recognise if a wrong button is selected and if so, finish the activity. As far as I can tell, the problem comes from the fact that the changed button is randomly selected and so I have no way of telling which of the buttons are the wrong ones until the program is running. Below is the code that I have so far:

```
ImageButton changedButton;
Random random = new Random();

int changedButtonNo;
int buttonSelect;

int usual = R.drawable.abc_ic_cab_done_holo_light;
int changed = R.drawable.abc_ic_cab_done_holo_dark;

int[] buttons = { R.id.imageButton1, R.id.imageButton2, R.id.imageButton3,    R.id.imageButton4, R.id.imageButton5, R.id.imageButton6 };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inspection_task_menu);

    buttonSelect = random.nextInt(6);
    changedButtonNo = buttons[buttonSelect];
    changedButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(changedButtonNo);
    changedButton.setImageResource(changed);

    //Decrease amount of time the stimuli is displayed over attempts
    CountDown(60);

    changedButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
            {
                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                recreate();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    //If any other button from the list is pressed, exit activity
}

public void CountDown(int milliseconds)
{
    new CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 1000)
    {
        @Override public void onTick(long toFinish)
        {
        }

        @Override public void onFinish()
        {
            changedButton.setImageResource(usual);
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
public void recreate()
{
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
View.OnTouchListener getOnTouch(ImageButton button) 
{
    return new View.OnTouchListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            if (v.getId() == changedButtonNo)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
                {
                    final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    recreate();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In  onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) You have view.id which will tell which button is pressed.

Comment: Yes but that is inside an onTouchListener that only gets fired when the changedButton is pressed and none of the other buttons. So a check inside the onTouch would be irrelevant.

Comment: And there you have it... you have to set an onTouch/ClickListener to all your buttons...how else you want to get the touches? Then in onTouch/Click ... if(v == changedButton) ... else ...

Comment: And why start a new activity for this? Can't you just start the randomize button stuff again?

Comment: I tried that. I did the following:

Comment: View.OnTouchListener getOnTouch(ImageButton button) 
 {
  return new View.OnTouchListener() 
  {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
   {
    if (v.getId() == changedButtonNo)
    {
     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
     {
      final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      toast.show();
      recreate();
     }
    }
    else
    {
     final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     toast.show();
     finish();
    }
    return true;
   }
  };
 }

Comment: Sorry, that comment was really messy. I have edited the code to show what else I tried. However, that doesn't work either.